# Selecionar primeiro com condicional

Tags: r, dplyr

Estou iniciando no R, e possuo um data frame semelhante a este a seguir:

```
x <- data.frame(cod_produto = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), 
            valordia = c(0,0,150.23,110.98,18.65,0), 
            data = c("2019-01-01","2019-01-02","2019-01-03","2019-01-01","2019-01-02","2019-01-03"))
```

Como retornar o primeiro dia em que ocorreu venda (`valordia > 0`)?

Tentei utilizar o pacote `dplyr`.

Answer (score 2):

Com `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

x %>% 
  filter(valordia > 0) %>% 
  arrange(data) %>% 
  slice(1)

cod_produto valordia       data
          2   110.98 2019-01-01
```

`filter` filtra os valores `> 0`;

`arrange` ordena as datas;

`slice` retorna somente a primeira obsevação, neste caso.

Se quiser saber quando ocorreu a primeira venda, não importando a data, é só retirar o `arrange` da função. Ficaria assim:

```
x %>% 
  filter(valordia > 0) %>% 
  slice(1)

  cod_produto valordia       data
            1   150.23 2019-01-03
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno. Há possibilidade de utilizar dentro de um summarize?

Comment: Como seria o uso (por exemplo, somar o `valordia`)?

Comment: Algo semelhante ao código a seguir. Somando o valor total das vendas e incluindo dois campos com a data da primeira e da última venda:

y <- x %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(cod_produto) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(totalVenda = sum(valordia),
                             dataPrimeiraVenda = ???,
                             dataUltimaVenda = ???)

Comment: Ao invés de `summarise` que retorna um resumo simples de uma operação, use `mutate`. Veja se atende ao que deseja:

`y <- x %>% 
  group_by(cod_produto) %>% 
  mutate(totalVenda = sum(valordia)) %>% 
  arrange(data) %>% 
  slice(c(1, n()))`

Comment: O código que você elaborou retorna duas linhas para cada produto (primeira data e última data). Porém, o que preciso é agrupar por código de produto (por isso estava usando o `summarise`). O resultado ficaria algo assim (em único registro para cada produto): `cod_produto`, `totalVenda`, `dataPrimeiraVenda`, `dataUltimaVenda`. Sendo que as datas da primeira e da última venda devem ser pelo campo `valordia > 0`

Comment: Você quer a data em colunas distintas? Isto é, `dataPrimeiraVenda` e `dataUltimaVenda`  e, se o `valordia > 0`? Se sim, segue:
`library(tidyr)

x %>% group_by(cod_produto) %>% 
  mutate(totalVenda = sum(valordia)) %>% 
  arrange(data) %>% 
  slice(c(1, n())) %>% 
  spread(key = data, value = totalVenda) %>% 
  filter(valordia > 0)`. O `totalVenda` está dentro das colunas datadas.

Comment: Para o data frame da pergunta, o resultado deveria ser assim: `structure(data.frame(cod_produto = c(1,2),totalVenda = c(150.23,129.63), dataPrimeiraVenda = c("2019-01-03","2019-01-01"), dataUltimaVenda = c("2019-01-03","2019-01-02")))`

Answer (score 0):

Com R base pode ser como se segue.
Primeiro transformar a coluna `data` numa coluna de classe `"Date"`.

```
x$data <- as.Date(x$data)
```

Agora, primeiro obter um índice das linhas da tabela ordenado por data e de seguida extrair a menor linha com `valordia > 0`.

```
i <- order(x$data)
x[i, ][min(which(x$valordia[i] > 0)), ]
#  cod_produto valordia       data
#4           2   110.98 2019-01-01
```

Comment: Rui, obrigado pelo retorno.